# Confuse about super function and self in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes, super, self

Here is the Code makes me confuse.

```
#python3 code
class SuperClass():
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
        super(SubClass,self).__init__(a+1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub = SubClass(1)
    print(sub.a) # result is 2
    # print(super(SubClass,sub).a) # AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'a'
```

I guess when invoke `super(SubClass,self).__init__(a+1)`,object `sub` passed into `self` in SuperClass,**not sub's parent object**.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is my guess correct? If correct,Why design like this ? If not,what is the right mechanis?
2. how can I pass value a+1 to SuperClass.a，in other words ,makes `super(SubClass,sub).a=2`

Thanks

**Edit 1**

Sorry about the Code.I misplaced two line `self.a=a` and `super(SubClass,self).__init__(a+1)`.I've correct the code above，and it's still support my guess.

**Edit 2**

```
#Let me explain my doubt in detail
#Generally We have a class Clazz
class Clazz():
    def f(self,a):
        pass
# and it's instance c
c = Clazz();
# when invoke method f of instance c, instance should be  implicit pass to the method as first parameter.
c.f(1) # formally equivalent to c.f(c,1)

#then back to my case
#In my logic
# super(SubClass,self) is a instance of class super ,when it invokes method __init__
# Similarly super(SubClass,self).__init__(a+1) should be equivalent to super(SubClass,self).__init__(super(SubClass,self),a+1)
class SuperClass():
    def __init__(self,a):   #  self=super(SubClass,sub)
        self.a = a          #  formally equivalent to super(SubClass,sub).a = a

# however it's not like as i thought
# super(SubClass,self).__init__(a+1) formally equivalent to super(SubClass,self).__init__(sub,a+1)
class SuperClass():
    def __init__(self,a):   #  self=sub
        self.a = a          #  formally sub.a = a
# it's contradictory
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `print(sub.a)` gives the expected `1`. You'll get `2` if you leave out `self.a = a` in the `__init__` method of `SubClass`.

Comment: Sorry,I misplace the code,@Matthias,you can try again

Comment: Now your question makes sense - in a way. But as @Ngoc-TinDanielNguyen explained: There is only one `a` attribute.

Comment: @Matthias,Invoker object `super(SubClass,self)`should be Implicit passed to `self`.For example,when invoke `obj.func(param)`,`obj` will be implicit passed to `self` ,in other word `obj.func(param)` equivalent to `obj.func(obj,param)`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It is not possible.

Long answer: Your `SubClass` inherits from `SuperClass`. When you initialize an object `sub` of `SubClass` it goes into the `__init__` of your `SubClass`. There it tells it to run the `__init__` of your `SuperClass` where the value of `sub.a` is set to `2` but immediately after in `SubClass` you write to `sub.a` the value 1.

The value `sub.a` is overwritten. It is gone. 
The variable exist only once and not twice. Your SubClass and SuperClass refer to the same variable in this case `sub.a`

If you want to preserve the value you need to define a new variable and write your value there.

```
#python3 code
class SuperClass():
    def __init__(self,var):
        self.a = var

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self,var):
        super(SubClass,self).__init__(var+1)
        self.b = var

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sub = SubClass(1)
    print(sub.a)
    print(sub.b)
```

Comment: Sorry,I misplace the code.And Why `self` is `sub` ,not `sub`'s parent when invoke `super(SubClass,self).__init__(var+1)`?Invoker object should be Implicit  passed to `self`,that's `sub`'s parent object

Comment: `self` is `sub` and not `sub`'s parent because `sub` has no parent. `SubClass` has a parent but `sub` is an instance of `SubClass` and not a class itself.

Comment: The first parameter of a method in a class is the object itself. By naming convention this parameter is called `self`. (There are exceptions, e.g. `@staticmethod`.) `sub` is the object and it has the methods defined in the class `SubClass`. Due to inheritance it also has the methods of `SuperClass` **unless** you overwrote it. If overwritten (here `__init__` was overwritten) you can access them with `super`. The attributes (here `a`) cannot be addressed individually. They only exist once regardless. You don't access attributes on a `super` object. You call functions with it.